# Post photo to Twitter using Curl and Windows command line

Tags: curl, twitter, command-line, twitter-oauth

I am using Curl to post to the Twitter API via the Windows command line.  I've already generated the oAuth headers and can post a tweet without a photo using:

```
curl -k -X POST "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json" -d "status=Test" -H "Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_nonce=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_signature=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"xxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_token=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_version=\"1.0\""
```

This works fine to post a status, but I can't seem to figure out how to post a photo with a status using the statuses/update_with_media endpoint.  I know this endpoint is depreciated, but I want to use it for the time being.

I've tried some variations of:

```
curl  -k -X POST "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json" -F \"[media]=@photo.jpg\" -F \"status=Test\" -H "Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"xxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_nonce=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_signature=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"xxxxxxx\", oauth_token=\"248911615-xxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_version=\"1.0\""
```

with no luck.  I always get a {"code":195,"message":"Missing or invalid url parameter."} error or {"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}.

I can't seem to figure out the right syntax and signature to post both a status and a photo.

I'd be happy to use the newer media/upload method if that's easier, but I haven't been able to get that working either.

Comment: I'd strongly advise you not to use `update_with_media` as it is very outdated. There are examples [here](https://itnext.io/a-beginners-guide-to-using-the-twitter-api-839c8d611b8c) and [here](https://github.com/twitter/twurl/issues/58) demonstrating the `media/upload` method using twurl. Using curl, you're probably not generating the signature correctly when your media is included.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use twurl as I can't install Ruby.  I need it to run via curl.exe from a shell command.  But I'll examine the examples to see if I can get any hints.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the syntax and signature to get the newer media/upload endpoint to work:

curl -k -X POST "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json" -F "media=@file.jpg" -H "Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_nonce=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_signature=\"xxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"xxxxxx\", oauth_token=\"xxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_version=\"1.0\""

The key is not including the media file as part of the signature