# How to upload image to Twitter using libcurl?

Tags: c++, twitter, libcurl

I'm trying to upload an image to Twitter using cUrl in a C++ application. Here there are the [docs for it in Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58161946/post-photo-to-twitter-using-curl-and-windows-command-line) it is a hint about how to do it.

I've tried to use it with a regular POST:

```cpp
    struct stat file_info;
    FILE* fd = fopen(image, "rb"); /* open file to upload */ 
    if(!fd) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot read file";
        exit(-1);
    }
    /* to get the file size */ 
    if(fstat(fileno(fd), &file_info) != 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    auto curl = curl_easy_init();

    const char* url = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?media_category=tweet_image";

    auto r = oauth_sign_url2(url, nullptr, OA_HMAC, "POST", api_key, api_secret_key, access_token, access_token_secret);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, r);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, fd);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    auto status = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

or using a form:

```cpp
    auto curl = curl_easy_init();

    auto form = curl_mime_init(curl);
    auto field = curl_mime_addpart(form);
    curl_mime_name(field, "media");
    curl_mime_filedata(field, image);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, form);

    struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;
    static const char buf[] = "Expect:";
    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);

    const char* url = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?media_category=tweet_image";

    auto r = oauth_sign_url2(url, nullptr, OA_HMAC, "POST", api_key, api_secret_key, access_token, access_token_secret);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, r);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    auto status = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Both fails so far... any hint would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to question: Don't use `struct` before a type in a variable declaration in C++. It is not required and may cause other issues down the road. Also consider using the C++ standard `std::filesystem::file_size` rather than the C/POSIX `fstat` and `FILE*`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is failing - are you seeing any error code from the Twitter API?